# Leaflet change GeoJSON geoms style

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style, web-mapping

I have GeoJSON that could be either a point or line and I am trying to make the layer red. Here is the code:

```
function styling(feature) {
    return {
        color: 'red',
    };
}               
geoms = new L.GeoJSON(jsdata,{
    style: styling,
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties.Address){
        return layer.bindPopup('<b>Segmentid</b> = ' +feature.properties.SegmentID
        +'<br>'+
        '<b>Address</b> = ' +feature.properties.Address)
        }
    else if(feature.properties.NodeID){
        return layer.bindPopup('<b>NodeID</b> = ' +feature.properties.NodeID
        +'<br>'+
        '<b>Street1</b> = ' +feature.properties.XST1
        +'<br>'+
        '<b>Street2</b> = ' +feature.properties.XST2
            )
        }
    else if(feature.properties.SegmentID){
        return layer.bindPopup('<b>SegmentID</b> = ' +feature.properties.SegmentID)
        }
    }
  });
geoms.addTo(map);
```

There is NO error anywhere and the color is the default blue.

Comment: You cannot make point red since it has no dimensions, but for lines it should work. Can you post a piece of your GeoJSON?

Comment: @TomazicM you're right the polylines do change...so how would I also change the marker?

Comment: Your saviour is `pointToLayer` option, see example https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

Comment: @TomazicM thanks that helped me solve it

Comment: Please provide your solution as an answer to your question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the geojson that will be passed through the leaflet geojson function will be either a point or line (never both together) I essentially created two styling arguments (not sure what you would describe them in my case).

for Lines - `style: styling` this took care of the styling


for Points - (credit to @TomazicM)

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
```

took care of the styling

```
function styling(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        weight: 5,
        opacity: 1,
        color: "#ff7800",
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 1
    };
}
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};          
geoms = new L.GeoJSON(jsdata,{
    style: styling,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties.Address){
        return layer.bindPopup('<b>Segmentid</b> = ' +feature.properties.SegmentID
        +'<br>'+
        '<b>Address</b> = ' +feature.properties.Address)
        }
    else if(feature.properties.NodeID){
        return layer.bindPopup('<b>NodeID</b> = ' +feature.properties.NodeID
        +'<br>'+
        '<b>Street1</b> = ' +feature.properties.XST1
        +'<br>'+
        '<b>Street2</b> = ' +feature.properties.XST2
            )
        }
    else if(feature.properties.SegmentID){
        return layer.bindPopup('<b>SegmentID</b> = ' +feature.properties.SegmentID)
        }
    }
  });
geoms.addTo(map);
```